# Getting a realtime dump of test's output

Tags: nunit

I have a big and long running set of tests; their textual output is redirected to a file, so I can view the logs later. However, NUnit writes this content to the file only when all test have finished.
Is it possible to make nunit write all test's output to a file immediately as this output is written by the test?

Comment: There's an active feature request for this: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1514

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature will be added in v3.4 https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1139